# Problem with jQuery loading content into div

Tags: jquery

```
$("body *").live('mouseover', function() {
    var currentId = $(this).attr('id');
    var html = "<div id='perfect4' style='font-size:10px;'><div id='pos1'><br>ID: " +currentId+ 
        " <br>Klasse: " +currentClass+ " </div><div id='pos' style='width:300px'></div></div>";
    $("#perfect4").html(html).replacewith(html);
});
```

that works in ff because there is an error (`replacewith`)
i know, `replaceWith` would be correct
but without this, it would not work

that doesnt work:

```
$("#perfect4").html(html)
```

why?

Comment: where you have define currentClass?

Comment: possible duplicate of [jquery problem with .live, .mouseover and .replaceWith / .html](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5979635/jquery-problem-with-live-mouseover-and-replacewith-html)

Answer (score 0):

You should not insert the html in the element, but instead just do

```
$("body *").live('mouseover', function() {
  var currentId = $(this).attr('id');
  var html = "<div id='perfect4' style='font-size:10px;'><div id='pos1'><br>ID: " +currentId+ 
    " <br>Klasse: " +currentClass+ " </div><div id='pos' style='width:300px'></div></div>";
  $("#perfect4").replacewith(html);    // without the .html() call
});
```

(assuming you already have a `'#perfect4'` element to start with)

Comment: well  but it isnt reloading the data if i move over another element in the document with the cursor

Comment: well so with this solution it doesnt work right how it should work