# jquery problem with .live, .mouseover and .replaceWith / .html

Tags: jquery

```
$("body *").live('mouseover', function() {
    var currentId = $(this).attr('id');
    var html = "<div id='perfect' style='font-size:10px;'><div id='pos1'><br>ID: " +currentId+ " <br>Klasse: " +currentClass+ " </div><div id='pos' style='width:300px'></div></div>";
    $("#perfect4").replaceWith(html);
});
```

that doesnt work
why

Comment: it doesnt update on mouseover

Comment: Where is the currentClass variable defined?

Comment: its not important with currentClass, its just a part of the whole sourcecode

Comment: What @tfbox said, plus isn't the `id` 'perfect', not 'perfect4'?

Comment: What doesn't? Can you edit your original question to have a few sentences outlining what you are trying to achieve. People will spend time trying to answer your qustion, so its generally curteous to put some effort into asking a well structured question. this is probably Why you have a -1 and a vote to close already. Also a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5976055/problem-with-jquery-loading-content-into-div

Comment: @NeXXeuS he is replacing prefect4 with perfect... @dream I think you re inventing the wheel look up jquery pretty print... http://james.padolsey.com/javascript/prettyprint-for-javascript/ ...

Comment: @val perfect4 is a div i appended before to the dom / body
in there are some infos to the element where you have your cursor on it

Comment: @dream I know what you are trying to do but do check pretty print thats what you are trying to do :) all I am saying why waste your time when you have it already done and light weight

Comment: no, you are totally wrong =)  its just a very small part of the whole application of mine =) and mine does something totally different then pretty print

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With the selector "body *" you are target all children of body. I think you would just try this (removing perfect4):

```
$("body").bind('mouseover', function(e) {
    var domTarget = e.target; // e.target grabs the node that triggered the event.
    var currentId = domTarget.id;
    var sHtml = "<div id='perfect' style='font-size:10px;'><div id='pos1'><br>ID: " +currentId+ " <br>Klasse: " +currentClass+ " </div><div id='pos' style='width:300px'></div></div>";
    var jPerfect = $("#perfect4");
    jPerfect.after(sHtml );
    jPerfect.remove();
});
```

replacing innerHTML in perfect4:

```
$("body").bind('mouseover', function(e) {
    var domTarget = e.target; // e.target grabs the node that triggered the event.
    var currentId = domTarget.id;
    var sHtml = "<div id='perfect' style='font-size:10px;'><div id='pos1'><br>ID: " +currentId+ " <br>Klasse: " +currentClass+ " </div><div id='pos' style='width:300px'></div></div>";
    $("#perfect4").html(sHtml);
});
```

Comment: when i mouseover antoher child of the body it should update the info in the div with the id perfect4  (that is much higher in the sourcecode, this is only a part of the complete one so there exits a div with this id containing the data)

Comment: Ah ok then change: 
 
 var jPerfect = $("#perfect4");
    jPerfect.after(html);
    jPerfect.remove();

for:
var jPerfect = $("#perfect4").html(html);

Comment: @dream `$("body").bind('mouseover', function() {` replace with `$("body").bind('mouseover', function(e) {` so you pass the `e` parameter to the callback

Comment: i need it for body *   so for all child elements

Comment: My fault. Replace "$('body').bind('mouseover', function() {" for "$('body').bind('mouseover', function(e) {"

Comment: how do i get more than the id like .css('color'), $(this).attr('src'); ... ?

Answer (score -1):

you can use this :

```
$("#perfect4").text(html);
```

or

```
$("#perfect4").val(html);
```

or

```
$("#perfect4").html(html);
```

Comment: doesnt work either  its not updating with .html  im using it in combination with body *, .live and mouseover

Comment: exactly, What do u want to do ?

Comment: get dynamically infos from each element on the website shown in a div